# The vmRSS value of /proc/$pid/status seems not accurate? Why?

Tags: linux, memory, proc

I wrote a test program to help me understand the output field of different memory utilities such as free,ps,top,/proc/$pid/status,/proc/$pid/smaps,/proc/$pid/statm etc. One question finally rose up and I could not manage to understand:

Question: The vmRss field of /proc/$pid/status is *not same* with the one calculated out of /proc/$pid/smaps (by adding up all the Rss field).

The former value should be source of the RSS output of "ps" command while the latter one source of "pmap -x" command.

The test program I wrote is to create 20 threads with identical procedure in which each thread call malloc(4*1024) 256 times, resulting in a memory footprint of 1MB per thread, therefore 1MB/thread * 20 thread = 20MB totally.

Based on this program, the output of VmRSS from /proc/$pid/status is

```
VmRSS:     16468 kB
```

which align with the output of ps

```
8941  0.0  0.1 4102600 16468 pts/22  Sl+  10:07   0:00 ./a.out
```

While the add-up of /proc/8941/smaps and output of pmap -x 8941 is:

```
$ cat /proc/8941/smaps | grep Rss | awk '{print $2}' | awk '{s+=$1} END {printf "%.0f\n", s}' /dev/stdin
22536
$ pmap -x 8941 | tail -n 1
total kB         4102604   22536   20992
```

The output of free command convinced me that my program do consume 20+MB memory, therefore the RSS value of "ps" and "/proc/$pid/status" does not make sense to me.

Can anybody explain what is happening? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Please refer Linux man-pages project at https://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/. They can explain what you are seeing.

As of this writing (release 5.13), [proc(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) says VmRSS in /proc/[pid]/status is inaccurate.

> VmRSS  Resident set size.  Note that the value here is the
> sum of RssAnon, RssFile, and RssShmem.  This value
> is inaccurate; see /proc/[pid]/statm above.

proc(5) says RssAnon and RssFile are inaccurate, so VmRSS must be inaccurate.

For accurate values you should refer /proc/[pid]/smaps (man page says so under /proc/[pid]/statm).

And, [ps(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html) says

> The SIZE and RSS fields don't count some parts of a process including
> the page tables, kernel stack, struct thread_info, and struct
> task_struct.  This is usually at least 20 KiB of memory that is always
> resident.  SIZE is the virtual size of the process (code+data+stack).

Answer (score 0):

It is not enough just to allocate memory, try to use this memory, try to fill it with some value in you app and the VmRSS will grow.